# How do I remove non-duplicate lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

How do I remove all non-duplicate lines in Vim ?
There are plenty of solutions for removing duplicates lines. I wanna do it backwards. I want to leave only those lines that have at least a duplicate.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: I'm lost: do you want to remove duplicates or non-duplicates? Maybe a before/after example would help?

Comment: I want the duplicate lines to stay and the unique lines removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%y               yank the whole buffer
:vnew             create a new vertical window
Vp                paste in place of line 1
:sort             sort the buffer
:%!uniq -u        remove duplicates
:%s/.*/g\/&\/d    turn every line into a :global command that deletes the matching line
:%y               yank the whole buffer
:bw!              delete that buffer 
                  (and close the window and move back to the original window)
:@"               execute the :global commands contained in the unnamed register
```

Which, admittedly, is a lot more typing than Kent's answer but, hopefully, demonstrates Vim's versatility.

Answer (score 6):

if you were on Linux box, give this line in vim a try:

```
:%!awk 'a[$0]++'
```

If you are looking for pure vim/vimscript solution, you could build a dictionary in vim, key is the line text, value is how many times the line occurred in buffer, finally filter out those `value ==1` entries.

read doc for `:h dict` `:h filter(`

Comment: This was a shorter solution than @romainl but I need all the duplicated lines and not only one line per duplicate. Will study dict and filter, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) now has a `:DeleteUniqueLinesIgnoring` command that does this.